# why os.path.isfile and os.path.islink return true for a soft link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system

I am trying to check whether a file is soft link or regular file. But when i am checking a soft-link using os.path.isfile and os.path.link both functions return True.

```
In [34]: os.path.isfile('/bin/lessfile')
Out[34]: True

In [35]: os.path.islink('/bin/lessfile')
Out[35]: True

In [36]: ll /bin/lessfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 8 Apr 29 15:22 /bin/lessfile -> lesspipe*
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? or i am missing any arguments?

Comment: You want to lstat.

Answer (score 4):

`islink` returns True because /bin/lessfile is a link. `isfile` returns True because the link points to file. Create a link pointing to a directory and test — `isfile` will return False.